# How to filter elements in a list inside a stream in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I want to **filter out certain elements inside a stream** that emits a **list of elements**.
For example **a simple model (Item)** that is the element inside the List:

```
class Item {
  int id;
  String title;
  bool isDone;
}
```

Then I´ve implemented a **Riverpod provider** that receives a *List* from some Service as a stream where I want to filter out certain Items based on one of its properties:

```
@riverpod
Stream<List<Item>> notDoneItems(NotDoneItemsRef ref) async* {
  // Get a list of Items as a stream from a service provider.
  final list = ref.watch(listItemsServiceProvider).listItems();

  // list = list.where(...) now I want to filter out all Items in the list
  // where isDone==true, so that only a list of items with isDone==false is returned

  yield* list;
}
```

My question is: I´m receiving a **List** here and I´m not able to use .where(). **How should the syntax look like** when trying to achieve a filter function inside a stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `list` variable is actually a `Stream<List<Item>>`, so you need to map it to a new stream using the [`map`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/map.html) method and do the filtering inside:

```dart
list.map((actualListAndNotAStream) => actualListAndNotAStream.where((element) => !element.isDone));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already in a Stream Provider, you can do the filtering using an explicit stream generator:

```
Stream<T> build() async* {
  await for (final e in ref.watch(listItemsServiceProvider).listItems()) {
    if (e meets some filtering) yield e;
  }
}
```

That essentially open-codes what where does, but with many fewer parens. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! Here´s the final solution that worked for me:

```
@riverpod
Stream<List<Item>> notDoneItems(NotItemsRef ref) async* {
  final list = ref.watch(listItemsServiceProvider)listItems();
  final newList = list.map((itemList) => itemList.where((item) => item.doneAt == null).toList());
  yield* newList;
}
```